How to write an open research section in a systematic review paper?
I was writing the open research section for my systematic literature review, where I identified various research areas from multiple research papers. However, my supervisor said my open research section was not adequate, as it should include open research areas based on my own experience or knowledge. I am quite confused. Can anyone please suggest how to write the open research section in a systematic review paper?

What you call an "open research section" is usually called "future research" or a "research agenda". I don't know what exactly your advisor told you or why, but I can affirm that such sections include both a collection of open questions gathered from the literature that are still unanswered as well as new questions that you propose "based on [your] own experience or knowledge". Both are valid. However, if you are an undergraduate (as suggested by the "research-undergraduate" tag of your question), I would not expect you to have so much to offer "based on [your] own experience or knowledge", so I am surprised that your supervisor would insist on that.
I wrote a working paper on "Developing Novel and Relevant Theoretical Contributions with Literature Reviews" that includes a section on how to gather and write questions that are as yet unanswered (pp. 12-13):

Unanswered Questions: Aggregative and Contrarian Contributions
After the preceding sections that present propositions of what is accepted from the  literature (aggregative) and what is newly proposed (reconciling and contrarian), the  final important section that we recommend for a research agenda is a presentation of  open-ended questions with uncertain expectations of their answers. There are two categories of such research questions. The first consists of a recapitulation of research  questions from the literature that are still unanswered. Since these are not new  questions, their value would be only aggregative. The second consists of completely new questions that either arise from conflicts in the literature or are different from what the literature has thus considered.

